# How can I adjust the margin top value based on previous div height?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am creating a website using materialize css, and I am created a fixed nav bar so the bellow div is hide and it is go under the above navbar. So I can fix it by using margin-bottom property, but depends on the device the nav bar height is increase or decrease so how can I solve this problem? also I don't like to use the media query.

```css
.fixedtop {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0A2445;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(14, 91, 128, 0.67);
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<nav class="fixedtop" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="col s12">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Settings</a>
        <ul class="right">
          <li><a href="sass.html"><i class="mdi-action-search"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="components.html"><i class="mdi-action-view-module"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript.html"><i class="mdi-navigation-refresh"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="mobile.html"><i class="mdi-navigation-more-vert"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
<!--If I use margin-top and adjust the div different device will not set peroperly (without media query)-->
<div>
  This div is gone under the navbar 
  </div>
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use media queries??

Comment: It can only be done with media queries or Javascript. Fixed positioning by definition is outside of the normal document flow.

Comment: yeah. media queries are real lifesavers.

Comment: without media query can't I solve this? then ok thanks for your help.

Comment: you can specify margin-top value in % instead of pixel.
Also the standard margin-top value for the div below navbar is always 70px, which is stated in bootstrap documentation. You can also use the same value here i.e give your below div style=margin-top:70px;